# Getting the absolute location of an image after a translate Animation

Tags: android, android-animation

I have an image. On the click of a button a translate animation happens on the images so that it slides to the left and you only end up seeing a certain percentage of the image.

Is there a way by which I can get the position of the image after the translate animation happens? I realize I can use a animation listener and do something in the OnAnimationEnd method. However, I am not sure what to do here...

How do I get the position that the image has moved to and set that as my layout params for the image?

I could really use your help here.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your current image location is x, y. You’re moving in x direction 100, y direction 50. So your current position is newx =x+100, newy=y+50. You will place image using your layout inside the onAnimationEnd method.

```
 TranslateAnimation TAnimation=new TranslateAnimation(0, 100, 0, 50)        
    TAnimation.setDuration(2000);
    TAnimation.setFillAfter(true);
    Image.startAnimation(TAnimation);
 TAnimation.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

        }

        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

        }

        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

            RelativeLayout RL=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.rl);
                param=new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams( LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            param.setMargins(x+100, y+50, 0, 0);
                Image.setLayoutParams(param);

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old, but It may help someone.
You can just add:

```
animation.setFillAfter(true);
```

or in Xml set:

```
 fillAfter = "true"
```

That's it. It will force the view to be in the new position